# If ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is locally cyclic then $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

It is a very common exercise in elementary group theory to prove that if ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. The usual proof seems to not require it to be cyclic but just locally cyclic. Is this correct? Are there any interesting further generalizations?

Comment: Yes, local cyclicity is sufficient: given $x,y\in G$, the subgroup generated by $xZ(G)$ and $yZ(G)$ in $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is finitely generated, hence cyclic. So there exists $w\in G$ and integers $r,s$ such that $xZ(G) = w^rZ(G)$ and $y=w^sZ(G)$, from which it follows that $x$ and $y$ commute.